# Cause of Netbeans error: package org.openide.util is declared in the unnamed module, but module com.customcode.spm does not read it

Tags: java, netbeans

I have a large, multi-project legacy code that has been building fine until a few weeks ago. I changed something and I can't figure out what caused the break, even backing out all my changes didn't help. It is a Netbeans project and I am getting the Netbeans error in the title.

Netbeans version 15, JVM version 15, Windows 10

My module-info.java is:

```
module com.customcode.spm
{
    requires com.customcode.common;  // <-- Module not found
    requires com.customcode.myplan;  // <-- Module not found
    requires java.xml;
    requires java.logging;
    requires java.desktop;
    requires java.management;
    requires org.openide.util;  // <-- Module not found
}
```

Amongst a bunch of other Netbeans dependencies, I have the following in the pom for this project (Note that my other projects have a similar pom with the same dependency and they compile fine):

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.netbeans.api</groupId>
        <artifactId>org-openide-util</artifactId>
        <version>${netbeans.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

I am guessing that the error is kind of a red herring as all my investigation into the project configuration haven't found anything wrong and I can't make any sense of the error.

If I comment out the "`requires org.openide.util;`" line, then I get the following errors for each class that uses it:

```
Compiling 51 source files to E:\hg\roche\MyPlanMaker\target\classes
incrementalBuildHelper#afterRebuildExecution
-------------------------------------------------------------
COMPILATION ERROR : 
-------------------------------------------------------------
com/customcode/spm/wizard/NewPanel1.java:[22,19] package org.openide.util is not visible
  (package org.openide.util is declared in the unnamed module, but module com.customcode.spm does not read it)
```

I need some help figuring out where to look for the source of the problem. Is there a way to look at the unnamed module? Or configure it out so it never gets used and I have to supply my own named modules (which I would prefer so I can control what happens during building and running)?

I have restarted Netbeans a couple times, cleared out its cache, deleted the module-info.java, edited the pom all to no avail.

A reference to a document that explains what is going on under the hood in Netbeans in the context of Java Modules and the Unnamed Module would help. I've read numerous documents that tell me how to create a new, very simple project using Java Modules but none of them tell me what Netbeans is doing with Java Modules and how it reads them. Several comments say that the above problem arises when you use classpath to include packages, which apparently does not play well with using Java Modules. But I don't use classpath (at least knowingly, where would I look in Netbeans to determine if it is using classpath?).

Answer (score 0):

The only solution that let me continue work was to remove the project's `module-info.java` AND clear out the NetBeans cache.

To clear out the Netbeans cache on Windows 10, go to your
`user directory\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\15` and delete everything.

Experimenting with older working versions I found that once I made a build that included the module-info.java file, something was stored in the cache so the error persisted even after reverting all changes. The same behavior was observed in Netbeans 14 and 15.

The following is my opinion:

I think that there is a bug in Netbeans where it doesn't handle moving from Pre-Java 9 projects to Post-Java 9 under certain conditions. I'm not sure exactly what those conditions are and my code is too large and proprietary to post.

In addition, the documentation is far too focused on how to do certain things (like create a Hello World program with 1 module) rather than explaining what is happening under the hood so these corner cases can be debugged. I place the blame for this on Netbeans development, Java development and the Google search algorithm which only finds the most simplistic matches to search criteria.